# Syntax error before '*' token, al compilar da este error

Tags: c, sintaxis

Tengo el problema que al compilar este codigo me aparece que en la linea 4 hay un error de sintaxis antes del '*', pero al revisar no logro encontrar el problema, el codigo es un tipo gestion escolar usando structs y apuntadores.
El error que me aparece es syntax error before '*' token, revise que estuviera todo bien declarado, hice este programa sin funciones para escribir en las structs y funciono bien, pero cuando hago la funcion es cuando me empezo a causar este problema.
Intente quitar en la definicion de la funcon el apuntador o un doble apuntador pero nada de eso funciona.
Estoy definiendo un array dinamico de tipo de dato de la estructura alumno

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 void registro(alumno *nuevoRegistro, int contador, int bandera);

 struct materias
{
 float matematicas;
 float quimica;
 float fisica;
};

struct alumno
{
 struct materias calificaciones;
 int numeroBoleta;
 char apellidoPaterno[20];
 char apellidoMaterno[20];
 char nombre[20];
};

typedef struct alumno alumno;

int main()
{
 alumno *nuevoRegistro;
 int contador = 0;
 int bandera = 1;
 int i;

 nuevoRegistro = (alumno *)calloc(1,sizeof(alumno));
 do{

     registro(nuevoRegistro, contador, bandera);
     if (bandera != 0)
     {
      nuevoRegistro = (alumno *)realloc(nuevoRegistro, (contador + 2)*sizeof(alumno));
      contador++;
     }
 system("cls");
 printf("Desea ingresar un nuevo alumno?\n 1 - Si\n 0 - No\n");
 scanf("%d", &bandera);

 system("cls");



}while(bandera != 0);

printf("Total de Alumnos Ingresados: %d\n", contador);

for (i = 0; i < contador; i++)
{
  printf("Alumno:%d\n", i + 1);
  printf("Numero de Boleta: %d\n",nuevoRegistro[i].numeroBoleta );
  printf("Apellido Paterno: %s\n",nuevoRegistro[i].apellidoPaterno );
  printf("Apellido Materno: %s\n",nuevoRegistro[i].apellidoMaterno );
  printf("Nombre: %s\n",nuevoRegistro[i].nombre);
  printf("Calificacion Matematicas: %d\n",nuevoRegistro[i].calificaciones.matematicas );
  printf("Calificacion Quimica: %d\n",nuevoRegistro[i].calificaciones.quimica );
  printf("Calificacion Fisica: %d\n",nuevoRegistro[i].calificaciones.fisica );
}

 free(nuevoRegistro);


return 0;
}

void registro(alumno *nuevoRegistro, int contador, int bandera)
 {
  printf("Gestion de Alumnos  (School edition)\n");
  printf("Ingrese los datos del Alumno\n");

  printf("Numero de Boleta\n");
  scanf("%d", &nuevoRegistro[contador].numeroBoleta);

  printf("Apellido Paterno\n");
  scanf("%s%*c", &nuevoRegistro[contador].apellidoPaterno);

  printf("Apellido Materno\n");
  scanf("%s%*c", &nuevoRegistro[contador].apellidoMaterno);

  printf("Nombre\n");
  scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &nuevoRegistro[contador].nombre);

  printf("Calificacion Matematicas\n");
  scanf("%f", &nuevoRegistro[contador].calificaciones.matematicas);

  printf("Calificacion Quimica\n");
  scanf("%f", &nuevoRegistro[contador].calificaciones.quimica);

  printf("Calificacion Fisica\n");
  scanf("%f", &nuevoRegistro[contador].calificaciones.fisica);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que cuando el compilador llega a la declaración:

```
void registro(alumno *nuevoRegistro, int contador, int bandera);
```

No tiene idea de qué es `alumno` porque está más adelante en el código.

Simplemente muévela luego del `typedef` y problema solucionado:

```
typedef struct alumno alumno;

void registro(alumno *nuevoRegistro, int contador, int bandera);

...
```